# Change layout or borders of my document without package {geometry}

Tags: packages, geometry, lyx-layouts, rendering, typearea

I want to set the borders of my `scrartcl` document.

Right now im doing this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2.4cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} 

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

How can I get exact the same border size or a border size near to the specifications above without the package `geometry`?

I read about the package `typeare` but how get the same settings as above?

Thanks der help.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `geometry`? AFAIK most LaTeX users use it in all of their documents (including me).

Comment: "If you have concrete specifications for the margins, typearea is not suitable. In this case, you should use the geometry package" (quote from the koma script user guide)